# Android Compatibility with multiple devices

Tags: java, android, xml

Ok, so I know that if I want to make images and text and buttons not get too squished in tiny devices and not be absolutely tiny in giant tablets I can create resource files that are distinct for each device and each orientation.

Is there a more concise way to do this? I.e. is there a way to have a single folder with all my resources multiplied by like a "screen scaling factor" so that every time I want to edit I don't have to go back and change 30 different resources and then check to make sure they all fit?

Thanks

Comment: I believe, as long as you use layouts sensibly it all scales automatically. The problem is that it looks pixilated if you blow up low res images and can be too much for the machine to handle if you scale down high res

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not have to create different sizes for each widget.

For `Button`, `TextView`, `ImageView` (and any other `Views`) you can set the `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height` properties in **dp** (Density-independent pixels).

This unit is - as we can guess from its name - independent from the density of the screen. It means that the result will be the same on every screen.

The only thing that you might have to create in multiple sizes is the icons. For that you have to follow the rules provided by Android about the ratio between the different densities. For more information, you can take a look at [this](http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html).

You can also create your icon in a XML file. This way, it will automatically fits to every screen. The problem is that this can be very difficult to create complex icons.

Answer (score 0):

Actually its efficient having several images for every device, its not the same loading 500px for a low end device than loading a 100px that its actually you need. so i suggest using `scaleType` in the ImageView and adjust your UI using dimens inside `android_layout_width` and   `android:layout_height` example:
`android:layout_width="@dimen/size"` and you can use different sizes based on your device.
another way is put the images under `drawable-nodpi` and scale in runtime so this will always fix the image as you need

```
public static int calculateInSampleSize(
            BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        final int halfHeight = height / 2;
        final int halfWidth = width / 2;

        // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
        // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
        while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
                && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
            inSampleSize *= 2;
        }
    }

    return inSampleSize;
}
```

you can look in android developer guide for further help scaling bitmaps Efficiently
http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html